# Magento 2.3.4: How to customize the default email template?

Tags: email-templates, magento2.3.4, luma-theme

The `Share` button on the product view page allows the customer to share the link to the product by email. I would like to customize the email template being used by this feature as seen in screenshot below. How do I go about replacing `LUMA` at the top with my store name?

[image]

Comment: The issue of "Temporary local problem" could be from the mail server you are connecting to. Check this post if it helps! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105354/server-response-451-451-temporary-local-please-try-later-when-sending-email

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just figured it out that our SMTP server has some issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I only needed to replace the LUMA logo with that of my store in the emails triggered by Shared button, I could do it under Content->Custom Theme> Transactional Emails as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]